# ambiguous tag "clustering", please tag either data-clustering or compute-cluster?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

The tag "clustering" sometimes means data-clustering, and sometimes compute-cluster(ing), roughly 50-50 —
noise for anyone following either of the two.
How hard would it be to ask future taggers "please tag either data-clustering or compute-cluster" ?

Comment: Ugh. Sounds pretty counter-intuitive to me - but if the suggestions get made when you start typing "cluster", why not...

Comment: @Pekka, right, that's when it should be made. (What would be more intuitive for you ?)